# Объединить 2 запроса в action, yii2

Tags: php, yii, yii2

Здравствуйте, есть у меня вопрос. Делаю альбом с категориями и подкатегориями. На первой страничке все категории, по нажатию открываться изображения данной категории. Как сделать так, чтобы при нажатии в екшине выводило и дочерение категории и фото данной категории, по аналогии с папками в виндовс.

Вот такой код action'a выводит изображения категории

```
$query = Content::find()
        ->select('content.*')
        ->with('category')
        ->where(['category_id' => $id]);

    $pagination = new Pagination(['totalCount' => $query->count(), 'pageSize'=>6]);
    $dataProvider = new ActiveDataProvider([
        'query' => $query,
        'pagination' => $pagination
    ]);
    return $this->render('album', [
        'dataProvider' => $dataProvider,
        'pagination' => $pagination,
    ]);
```

Получается вот такой вывод

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Нужно чтобы выводило изображения категории, и дочерние категории (если такие есть)

Получается, нужно что-то типа такого кода

```
$query = Category::find()
        ->from('category')
        ->where(['parent_id' => $id]);
```

Проверял, он выводит дочерние категории. 
Но вот как этот запрос обьединить с первым, и как вывести во view незнаю, код вывода

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
    foreach ($models  as $model) { ?>
        <div class="col-sm-6 col-md-4">
            <div class="thumbnail">
                <a href="/content/view?id=<?= $model->id?>">
                    <img src="<?= '/backend/web/'.$model->content_image ?>" alt="image" width="400" height="400"  class="img-rounded">
                </a>
            </div>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>
</div>
</div>
```

Кто что думает?? Возможно когда-то решали подобную задачу?

Comment: Лично я смутно понял ваш вопрос ... Рекомендую перефразировать его + структуру БД выложить ... (кнопка «Править»)

Comment: перефразировал, что можете сказать теперь?

Answer (score 1):

А если через связи сделать ? Правда не уверен будет ли работать это. В модели Category

```
public function getChildren()
{
    return $this->hasMany( Category::className(), ['parent_id' => 'id'] );
}
```

Тогда дочерние будут доступны как

```
$category->children
```

А вообще рекомендую использовать это https://github.com/creocoder/yii2-nested-sets.

Comment: Связи у меня прописаны,                                                                                                public function getContents()
    {
        return $this->hasMany(Content::className(), ['category_id' => 'id']);
    }     Я так обращаюсь чтобы вывести имя категории $this->title = $model->category->name                                               Доступ получается есть, просто одновременно вывести и одно и второе я не могу, потому , что это 2 разных запроса, а я незнаю как их передать.

Comment: Это связь для выборки подкатегорий категории :) А у вас связь выборки записей(ну или чего там у вас, телефонов) в зависимости от категории.

Comment: А где тогда мне прописать именно чтобы выводило дочерние категории главной --- я вот так писал то работало , только тогда я немогу вывести изображение самой категории , ->from('category')
        ->where(['parent_id' => $id]);

Comment: ->with('category') - category, это связь ведь, один к одному, правильно ? каким образом она у вас выглядит в модели ?

Comment: public function getCategory()
    {
        return $this->hasOne(Category::className(), ['id' => 'parent_id']);
    }  связь в таблице самой на себя,... как то лучше я не придумал, потому что при создании дочерней категории, главную выбираем из той же самой таблицы

Comment: Вы можете привести код ваших моделей - Content и Category ?

Answer (score 0):

Для многоуровневой вложенности категорий:

В модели категории:

```
public function getParent()
{
    $parent=$this->hasOne(Category::class, ['id' => 'parent_id']))->one();
    return parent->getParent()?:$this;
}

public function getParentId(){
    return $this->parent->id;
}
```

В запросе

```
->where(['parentId'=>$id]);
```

ps. Не проверял. Попробуйте, если не получиться, придумаем другое решение:)